# IOS 6 Objective-c xcode Storyboard, Login-flow, Navigation flow, screen flow

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm desperate. I've been trying to figure it out for ages and I just can't seem to find the answer.

I'm trying to create the same login flow as Pintrest. Can anyone help me? I trying to figure out whether they are using a navigation controller or just single view with custom navigation?

Please help, I'm really trying to create something every similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's `UINavigationController` used with multiple `UIViewControllers`

For `SIGNUP` -- Next screen is pushed via `UINavigationController` which consist of some background image (on `UIScrollView`, of course); with two `UIButton` --  `Facebook` && `Twitter` **Also**, It has used Custom `UIButton` with **no background image** for `sign up with your email address`.

For `LOGIN` -- Next screen is pushed via `UINavigationController` which consist of Background image (here no UIScrollView is used, simply put it on UIViewController's View); with Three `UIButtons` with background images -- `Facebook` && `Twitter` && `Email Address`

Hope it helps you to start. Good Luck.

Comment: thank you very much. I'll start doing the tutorials on that :)

Comment: Is there a difference between the UINavigationController and the UINavigationViewController?